# Multi-threaded program lock on the inner Stack of a List<Stack<Person>>. Is this ok to do?

Tags: c#, multithreading, locking

I am wondering if this would be valid locking.
In my class (which is a Singleton) I have this line of code:

```
private List<Stack<Person>> _persons = List<Stack<Person>>();
```

I am wondering if this code would work?

```
Stack s = GetCorrectStack();  // pick a stack from the _persons
lock(s)
{
   // do a push or pop on the s stack
}
```

I ask this because all the examples on locking seem to be locking on a member of the class.

Also instead of just using a Stack like I did above could I use a ConcurrentStack and just avoid using the lock?

Comment: `lock` does not care where its argument comes from. It cannot know that it came from a field. It only cares about object identity.

Comment: It's very difficult to assess whether code is safe/correct or not when we're just shown a small piece in isolation. What else operates on `_persons` and the objects contained within it?

Comment: What is your code for `GetCorrectStack` method?

Answer (score 2):

> I am wondering if this code would work?

It depends on what the scope of the `Stack` is. If you're returning the stack where someone can externally modify it, don't use it as a lock. This also means that `GetCorrectStack` must be thread safe, because a `List<T>` is not.

You can definitely use `ConcurrentStack` instead for thread-safety. You could also use a `ConcurrentBag<T>` instead of a `List<T>`. Note that the former is unordered, as opposed the latter.

As a side note - If you're using `GetCorrectStack` often, which iterates the entire list, you might be better off with a `ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>` which is suited for fast look-ups.

Comment: `ConcurrentBag<T>` and `List<T>` does not function the same.

Comment: @Bauss Expand on what you mean by *"don't function the same"*. Other than the fact `ConcurrentBag<T>` isn't ordered.

Comment: Yeah that's what I mean. It's not predictable, like `List<T>` - consider the following. https://dotnetfiddle.net/xTUaGl

Comment: @Bauss I don't see how that's unpredictable, if the first thing the documentation says is that the bag is unordered.

Comment: Well it depends on implementation, but let's say you use `List<T>` a lot of places and then you start implementing multi-threading. It may not be as simple as just replacing `List<T>` with `ConcurrentBag<T>` because it might not produce the same results that you had already been working with, which can cause unpredictable results and/or bugs. Of course if you start by implementing it then it does not create an unpredictable result, considering you're not replacing existing code with it.

Comment: @Bauss They are not a 1-1 replancement, I agree. But if you care for ordering, perhaps you're better off locking on the `List<T>`.